# Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {rendered, protected})

Tags: reactjs

Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {rendered, protected}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

I'm getting this error. I was following a tutorial and everything was working perfectly until I tried to render the { content, link, title }. now  I get this error. Anyone know why?

```
import React, {Component, } from 'react'

class QuoteMachine extends Component {

constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {
         quote: {
             content: "",
             link: "",
             title: ""
         },
         hasQuote: false
    }
    this.END_POINT = 'https://quotesondesign.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/?orderby=rand'
}

getRandomQuote = event => {
    fetch(this.END_POINT)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
        console.log(data)
    if (data[0].content && data[0].title && data[0].link ) {
        let { quote } = this.state;
        let quoteData = data[0];
        quote.content = quoteData.content;
        quote.link = quoteData.link;
        quote.title = quoteData.title;
        this.setState( { quote }, () => {
            if(this.state.hasQuote === false){
                this.setState( { hasQuote: true })
            }
        }
            )
    } else {
        console.error("no quote")
    }})
}

renderQuote = () => {
    const { title, content, link } = this.state.quote;

    return(
        <div>
            <h1>{content}</h1>
            <h1>{link}</h1>
            <h1>{title}</h1>


        </div>
    )
}

render () {
    const { hasQuote } = this.state; 
    console.log(this.state);
    console.log("yahbro")
    return (

        <React.Fragment>
            <h1>Quote Machine</h1>
            <button onClick={this.getRandomQuote }>Click For New Quote</button>
            <br></br>
            { hasQuote === true ? 
            this.renderQuote()
            : "no quote yet" }
        </React.Fragment>
    )
}
}

export default QuoteMachine;
```

Comment: Will be interesting to see what `content` looks like.

Comment: My guess is it is an object.

Comment: Can you post a link to the tutorial?

Answer (score 0):

Took the liberty to snoop into your API response. `content` appears to be an object which you can not use as a React child (thing inside `{}`). Strings are fine.

For example this should work:

```
<h1>{content.rendered}</h1>
<h1>{link}</h1>
<h1>{title}</h1>
```